# Midpoint Rule with n = 4 to approximate the area of the region bounded between the curves

Tags: calculus

Use the Midpoint Rule with $n = 4$ to approximate the area of the region bounded between the curves $y = \sin^2 (\pi x/4$) and $y = \cos^2 (\pi x/4$) for $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$.

So here $\delta x = 1/4 = 0.25$

So, the final answer will be this:
$0.25((\cos(.125\pi /4)^2 + (\cos(.375\pi /4)^2 + (\cos(.625\pi /4)^2 +(\cos(.875\pi /4)^2) - 0.25((\sin(.125\pi /4)^2 + (\sin(.375\pi /4)^2 + (\sin(.625\pi /4)^2 + (sin(.875\pi /4)^2)$

I put this in calculator and get $0.77$ however, my homework system says it's wrong. I have no clue where I'm wrong.

Any help?

Comment: Do you know the analytical result?  Or can you derive it?

Comment: @rlgordonma I'm not sure what you mean by it. I solved it right now on paper and got the aforementioned equation.

Comment: I mean actually doing out the integral in closed form as a baseline comparison for your midpoint result, i.e. $\int_0^1 dx\,(\cos^2{(\pi x/4)}-\sin^2{(\pi x/4)})$, which just so happens to equal $\int_0^1 dx\,\cos{(\pi x/2)}$.

Comment: @rlgordonma No I haven't done that way since doing that will give a much better approximation than by using the mid point rule (we must use mid point rule).

Comment: I meant to check your work, as well as to see another way (note how I transformed the integral into something simpler).

Comment: @rlgordonma So this way, I get area to be 0.50. Not sure how correct/incorrect that is.

Comment: I will demonstrate in the answer below.

Comment: Omit the $\color{red}{\text{incorrectly placed}}$ parentheses.
$0.25(\color{red}(\cos(.125\pi /4)^2 + \color{red}(\cos(.375\pi /4)^2 + \color{red}(\cos(.625\pi /4)^2 +\color{red}(\cos(.875\pi /4)^2) - 0.25(\color{red}(\sin(.125\pi /4)^2 + \color{red}(\sin(.375\pi /4)^2 +\color{red} (\sin(.625\pi /4)^2 + \color{red}(sin(.875\pi /4)^2)$

Comment: If you entered the above into your calculator, it evaluated $.25*(-.25)$ times the sines. (That agrees with your result of $\approx.77$.)

Comment: Why is the line breaking so strange?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is right, although the first version of the OP had parentheses in odd places. Undoubtedly the issue is improper use of the calculator. Wrong parentheses maybe. Or even something silly like being in degree mode.

Let us do the calculation again, carefully. I am much too lazy to do all that squaring. So let us note that we want to approximate
$$\int_0^1 \left(\cos^2(\pi x/4)-\sin^2(\pi x/4)\right)\,dx.$$
But $\cos 2t=\cos^2 t-\sin^2 t$.

So we want to approximate
$$\int_0^1\cos(\pi x/2)\,dx.$$

Now we can do the Midpoint Rule stuff without wearing out our fingers. Note that in principle this should give **exactly** the same number as what one gets through your calculation, just a lot fewer key presses, so a lot fewer opportunities for error.  I get about $0.6407$.

The exact answer is $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$, which is about $0.6366$. Am a little surprised $n=4$ got us this close.   Midpoint Rule rules!

Comment: Thank, that helped. But I still get 0.67: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.25%28cos%280.125pi%2F2%29+%2B+cos%280.375pi%2F2%29+%2B+cos%280.625pi%2F2%29+%2B+cos%280.775pi%2F2%29%29 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KaranGoel:  $\frac 78=0.875,$ not $0.775$.  See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.25%28cos%280.125pi%2F2%29+%2B+cos%280.375pi%2F2%29+%2B+cos%280.625pi%2F2%29+%2B+cos%280.875pi%2F2%29%29 which agrees with André Nicolas

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_rule) says the error bound [given that the second derivative is bounded by $(\frac {\pi}2)^2$] is $\frac {\pi ^2}{4}\frac 1{24}\frac 1{16}\approx 0.0064$.  We are about $\frac 23$ of that.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer is

$$\int_0^1 dx \: \left [\cos^2{\left (\frac{\pi}{4} x \right )} - \sin^2{\left (\frac{\pi}{4} x \right )} \right ] = \int_0^1 dx \: \cos{\left (\frac{\pi}{2} x \right )} = \frac{2}{\pi} \approx 0.63662$$

Note how I used the double-angle identity for the cosine.  Now do the same in the midpoint approximation, which should look like:

$$\frac{1}{4} \left [ \cos{\left (\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{8} \right )} + \cos{\left (\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{3}{8} \right )} + \cos{\left (\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{5}{8} \right )} + \cos{\left (\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{7}{8} \right )} \right ] \approx 0.64073$$

Answer (score 0):

I calculated your sum as is and got $0.6407$. So actually it is important that you check your calculator steps individually to see where a mistake is happening. is it on radians? are your doing the squares correctly, etc. Do one terms at a time for a well known angle such as $\pi/4$ and check.